# Xamarin iOS Bluetooth peripheral scanning never sees any peripherals

Tags: ios, .net-core, xamarin.ios, ios-bluetooth

I am trying to create a **Xamarin.Forms** app that will run on both iOS and Android. Eventually I need instances of the app to communicate with each other via Bluetooth, but I'm stuck on getting the iOS side to do anything with Bluetooth. I originally tried to work with **Plugin.BluetoothLE** and **Plugin.BLE**, but after a week and a half I was not able to get advertising or scanning to work on either OS with either plugin, so I decided to try implementing simple Bluetooth interaction using the .NET wrappers of the platform APIs, which at least are well documented. I did get scanning to work fine on the Android side. With iOS, though, what I have right now builds just fine, and runs on my iPad without errors, but the **DiscoveredPeripheral** handler is never called, even though the iPad is just a few inches from the Android tablet and presumably should be able to see the same devices. I have verified this by setting a breakpoint in that method, which is never reached; and when I open the Bluetooth Settings on the iPad to make it discoverable the app version on the Android tablet can see it, so I don't think it's an iPad hardware issue.

It seems obvious that there is simply some part of the process I don't know to do, but it's not obvious (to me) where else to look to find out what it is. Here is the code for the class that interacts with the **CBCentralManager** (as far as I understand from what I've read, this should include everything necessary to return a list of peripherals):

```
using MyBluetoothApp.Shared; // for the interfaces and constants
using CoreBluetooth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyBluetoothApp.iOS.PeripheralScanner))]
namespace MyBluetoothApp.iOS
{
    public class PeripheralScanner : IPeripheralScanner
    {
        private readonly CBCentralManager manager;
        private List<IPeripheral> foundPeripherals;

        public PeripheralScanner()
        {
            this.foundPeripherals = new List<IPeripheral>();

            this.manager = new CBCentralManager();
            this.manager.DiscoveredPeripheral += this.DiscoveredPeripheral;
            this.manager.UpdatedState += this.UpdatedState;
        }

        public async Task<List<IPeripheral>> ScanForService(string serviceUuid)
        {
            return await this.ScanForService(serviceUuid, BluetoothConstants.DEFAULT_SCAN_TIMEOUT);
        }

        public async Task<List<IPeripheral>> ScanForService(string serviceUuid, int duration)
        {
            CBUUID uuid = CBUUID.FromString(serviceUuid);
            //this.manager.ScanForPeripherals(uuid);
            this.manager.ScanForPeripherals((CBUUID)null); // For now I'd be happy to see ANY peripherals

            await Task.Delay(duration);
            this.manager.StopScan();

            return this.foundPeripherals;
        }

        private void DiscoveredPeripheral(object sender, CBDiscoveredPeripheralEventArgs args)
        {
            this.foundPeripherals.Add(new CPeripheral(args.Peripheral));
        }

        private void UpdatedState(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            CBCentralManagerState state = ((CBCentralManager)sender).State;
            if (CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn != state)
            {
                throw new Exception(state.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of understanding what I'm missing?

EDIT: O...K, I've discovered quite by accident that if I do this in the shared code:

```
IPeripheralScanner scanner = DependencyService.Get<IPeripheralScanner>();
List<IPeripheral> foundPeripherals = await scanner.ScanForService(BluetoothConstants.VITL_SERVICE_UUID);
```

twice in a row, it works the second time. I feel both more hopeful and much more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem was that in the first instantiation of **PeripheralScanner**, **ScanForService** was being called before State was updated. I tried many ways of waiting for that event to be raised so I could be sure the state was **PoweredOn**, but nothing seemed to work; polling loops simply never reached the desired state, but if I threw an Exception in the **UpdatedState** handler it was thrown within milliseconds of launch and the state at that time was always **PoweredOn**. (Breakpoints in that handler caused the debugging to freeze with the output **Resolved pending breakpoint**, which not even the VS team seems to be able to explain).

Reading some of the Apple developer blogs I found that this situation is most often avoided by having the desired action occur within the **UpdatedState** handler. It finally soaked into my thick head that I was never seeing any effects from that handler running because the event was being raised and handled on a different thread. I really need to pass the service UUID to the scanning logic, and to interact with a generic List that I can return from **ScanForService**, so just moving it all to the handler didn't seem like a promising direction. So I created a singleton for flagging the state:

```
internal sealed class ManagerState // .NET makes singletons easy - Lazy<T> FTW
{
    private static readonly Lazy<ManagerState> lazy = new Lazy<ManagerState>(() => new ManagerState());
    internal static ManagerState Instance { get { return ManagerState.lazy.Value; } }
    internal bool IsPoweredOn { get; set; }

    private ManagerState()
    {
        this.IsPoweredOn = false;
    }
}
```

and update it in the handler:

```
private void updatedState(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    ManagerState.Instance.IsPoweredOn = CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn == ((CBCentralManager) sender).State;
}
```

then poll that at the beginning of **ScanForService** (in a separate thread each time because, again, I will not see the updates in my base thread):

```
    while (false == await Task.Run(() => ManagerState.Instance.IsPoweredOn)) { }
```

I'm not at all sure this is the best solution, but it does work, at least in my case. I guess I could move the logic to the handler and create a fancier singleton class for moving all the state back and forth, but that doesn't feel as good to me.